# Rails Reduce number of queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this code but it is performing WAAAY too many queries for my liking:

```
  all.includes(:cycles).each do |coaster|
    coaster.cycles.all.each do |cycle|
      unless coaster.length == nil
        unless cycle.date == nil
          if Date.parse(cycle.date).year == options[:year]
            distance += coaster.length
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

On line 1 I told it to include the cycles but it looks like line 2 is doing a separate query for each coaster's cycles, ontop of the larger simple query on line 1.

Is there a way to do exactly this but reduce the number of queries?

Comment: remove `all` from the second line - it creates a new reloation object which is not preloaded.

Comment: @BroiSatse Awesome! Thanks. Will look into that to help me understand further. Thankyou!  Feel free to add that as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `all`, it creates a new relation object which is not preloaded. If you want to understand it slightly more, I have given a talk on that subject quite recently: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/6731-activerecord-vs-n-1

Comment: @BroiSatse  Yes, Great talk, very informative. Thanks for sharing.